# Is the latest stable release or the latest LTS release more suitable for a development machine?

Tags: development, versions, lts

I was wondering which version of Ubuntu is better for my laptop, the current LTS release or the latest stable (but not LTS) release.

Is it always recommended to go for the latest version for personal laptop?

Is it advised to wait for several months after the version was released before installing it, so that the version can be more stable? If yes, does the CD got right after the release become less useful?

I plan 50 GB for Ubuntu partitions, 20 GB for root and 26 GB for home and 4 GB for swap.

My main use is programming with several popular programming languages and database and typesetting and browsing internet, seldom gaming, and therefore I will install related applications and compile some libraries for use in programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use the latest stable release

As it is predominantly a development machine, I would go with the latest stable version, as it has more up to date libraries and programming tools. As a normal release, it is not supported for as long as the LTS. I don't see this as a problem because you will probably want to have the newer versions installed by the time the support expires.

LTS versions are more suitable for business users and home users who don't want to worry about upgrading every 6 months.

Comment: Is a version that was just released officially stable enough, or better to wait several months to install the current version? If second, does the official CD got right after the release become less useful?

Comment: @Tim - The stable release is stable enough. As long as the release name doesn't contain `alpha`, `beta` or `rc`, it is the stable version. I have always found the stable version stable enough. I do generally wait a week or 2 before installing the new version but mainly to avoid the high traffic on the servers for downloading the ISO images and updating/installing software.

Answer (score 1):

The 10.04 is the long-term support (LTS) distribution; but, 10.10 is the latest - with better driver support and newer kernel.