# Which version to newly install prior to an LTS release, the latest point release or the current LTS?

Tags: upgrade, lts, versions

As of originally writing this question (Dec. '21), we're months away from a new Ubuntu LTS version (Apr. '22). This question does apply to any timeframe prior to an LTS release though.

I have received a new machine for work, which I intend to run the latest LTS when it is available. However, now I need to decide which OS to install. Should I install the current LTS (20.04) or the latest Ubuntu (21.10)?

Since I intend to upgrade to 22.04 LTS when it will be available, there is one OS upgrade I am bound to make, and upgrading Ubuntu to the next LTS should be possible from the current LTS or the latest point release.

Below, I made a list of points which direct me in one or the other direction. I guess some people might come up with more points.

- Installing the current LTS (Ubuntu 20.04)

  - Consistency: sticking to LTS releases for production purposes
- Installing the latest point release (Ubuntu 21.10)

  - Recency: the software of the latest point release is closer to the software of the upcoming LTS

Are there any recommendations for this scenario?

---

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25493/is-the-latest-stable-release-or-the-latest-lts-release-more-suitable-for-a-devel) on whether to use the latest point release vs. the latest LTS does and does not apply in my case, since I do not intend to upgrade every 6 months, however, I fully intend to upgrade once the impending LTS is released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Try Both

Download the ISO files for both the 20.04 and the 21.10 and burn them into two USB drives. Boot from each of them in turn. Use the **Try Ubuntu** option and verify all the hardware peripherals work in the version you are trying.

Pick the version that works for your new computer.

## The Reason

The Ubuntu 20.04.3 HWE currently (in December 2021) uses the kennel version 5.11 while the version 21.10 uses kernel version 5.13. The newer kernel may have support for some peripherals such as the WiFi card in your brand new computer.

Note if you install Ubuntu 20.04 now, it will be updated to kernel 5.13 in February 2022.

## Advice

Whichever version of Ubuntu you install now, wait for the first point update, that is 22.04.1 (probably August 2022) before you upgrade to the next LTS version.

Hope this helps

Comment: The hardware enablement (HWE) is a good point. While up to now all answers point to using the LTS, if possible, this answer makes two good points: the HWE and waiting for the first snapshot of the impeding LTS version.

Answer (score 2):

1. Point releases tend to be a bit more unstable than LTS releases.
2. It's always better to install a new release from scratch instead of upgrading an earlier one.
3. **20.04** will be supported for at least a year after **22.04** has been released, depending on the flavour you install, and you won't have to install the new one right away.

Judging from these, I'd use **20.04**.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use the LTS, because it generally has better driver support (especially AMDGPU-PRO) and more stupid little bugs could have been fixed in 1.6 year (LTS) than 2 months (normal). But as user68186 suggests, if the 21.10 works better for you, go with that.